# How to add text "Hello World" to WebControl like <h1>Hello World</h1>

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Need help finding how to add text to a web control in asp.net.  Looking for the simplest solution if possible or using a control builder if thats simple.

Example html to be generated by WebControl:

```
<h3>Hello World</h3>
```

Example of my best attempt so far:

```
WebControl wc = new WebControl(HtmlTextWriterTag.H3);
wc.????
```

Answered below at least two versions:

1. HtmlGenericControl... can use with var
   var h3_hgc = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
       h3_hgc.InnerText = "Hello World";
2. LiteralControl which is derived from WebControl
   LiteralControl hwLiteralControl = new LiteralControl("Hello World");
   wc.Controls.Add(hwLiteralControl);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I like to put literal strings into the pages is by using the Literal tag

Default.aspx:

```
<h1><asp:Literal ID="litHeader" runat="server" /></h1>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    litHeader.Text = "Hello World";
  }
}
```

What I like about using the Literal control is there is no extra markup that gets rendered to the HTML.  This works great anytime I want to display anything to the screen but will not be referencing it later to get values out.

How it Rendered:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Edit:

The example above is a simple demo approach.  When output anything to the screen you want to make sure you protect against Cross Site Scripting attacks.  Since you are using ASP.Net Web Forms, I would get the NuGet package "Antixss" from Microsoft. (Use Antixss' Encoder.HtmlEnocde() over Server.HtmlEncode, [heres why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/07/09/differences-between-antixss-htmlencode-and-httputility-htmlencode-methods.aspx))

Here is how you would use it:

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Security.Application;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /* username is pulled from a datastore*/
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    litHeader.Text = Encoder.htmlEncode(username);
  }
}
```

Comment: That works great.  I think I need to get all these web controls mapped. thx

Answer (score 6):

[Headings](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp) are not  server webcontrols but html elements. If you need to create it dynamically:

```
var h3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
h3.InnerHtml = "Hello World";
container.Controls.Add(h3);
```

Where `container` is the control where you want to add it.

Comment: Does it matter if its InnerText or InnerHtml?

Comment: Test it. I think both works but html would only be interpreted if you'd use `InnerHtml` (f.e. `"Hello<br>World"`).